# Failing to upgrade sonarqube using mysql

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, upgrade, configure

I am trying to configure/start SonarQube with MySQL.
I installed everything including sonar DB and sonar user with proper permission.
when I browse 127.0.0.1/sonar, I get 'under maintenance'.
when I browse to /setup to upgrade, I get this message

```
Database connection cannot be established. Please check database status and JDBC settings.
```

here is my config

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false
jdbc.default.username=sonar
jdbc.default.password=hpP@ssw0rd
```

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v60.AddUuidPathColumnToProjects
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute ALTER TABLE projects ADD (uuid_path VARCHAR (1500) NULL)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate column name 'uuid_path'
2017.02.15 10:43:05 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v60.AddUuidPathColumnToProjects

Comment: SonarQube logs will help you understand the problem. Check in _<sonar_install_dir>/logs_. If needed update your question with relevant log findings, and details on SonarQube version too.

Comment: Which SonarQube version were you previously using ? (the fact that you got '_under maintenance_' means that a SonarQube DB was already deployed at your DB URL).